# How To Convert result into Date in Javascript?

Tags: apex, javascript, date, javascript-remoting

```
public class MyCustomController1
 {

public class studObjectwrap
     {public String D_ob{get;set;}}

@RemoteAction 
public static String createRecord(String jsonObjResult){  
//Some Code od Json Deserialization
Student__c st=new Student__c();
//Converting Date Into Salesforce Date Format i.e MM/DD/YYYY
          String strTest = sc.D_ob;
          String[] arrTest = strTest.split('-');
          String datetosend=arrTest[1]+'/'+arrTest[2]+'/'+arrTest[0];
          sc.D_ob=datetosend;
         //Parsed into Date
          st.DOB__c= date.parse(sc.D_ob);
}

@RemoteAction    
    public static Student__c fetchRecord()
    {
        Student__c student=[
                            SELECT DOB__c
                            FROM Student__c 
                            order by CreatedDate desc limit 1
                           ];
        System.debug(student);
        return student;
    }
```

//VisualForce Page

```
function fetchRecord() {     
         MyCustomController1.fetchRecord(handlefetchStudent); 
       }

function handlefetchStudent(result,event){
         if(event.type == 'exception') {
              alert(event.message);
          } else {
         console.log(result.DOB__c.toString());
          }
```

//but date stored as 1/1/2017 in salesforce org i want same date how to do it?

//Output on console=1483228800000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field is being written out in epoch time (the number of millseconds since January 1st, 1970). To get it back to a normal date, use the Date constructor:

```
console.log(new Date(result.DOB__c));
```

You could have also avoided this issue by serializing the result into JSON before returning, and deserializing afterwards:

```
@RemoteAction public static String fetchRecord() {
    // ...
    return JSON.serialize(student);
}

// ... In JS
console.log(JSON.parse(result));
```

Comment: Somehow i did it..but thank you so much @sfdcfox